# Android: change listview item with view?

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I am working on a library to make a listview that looks like the samsung swipe contact gesture.

[image: Samsung contact swipe]

This is my OnTouchListener:

```
for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
     child = getChildAt(i);
     child.getHitRect(rect);
     if (rect.contains(x, y)) {
          itemView = child;
          downX = motionEvent.getRawX();
          velocityTracker = VelocityTracker.obtain();
          velocityTracker.addMovement(motionEvent);

          Log.d("Swipe", "Swipe down item: " + i);
          break;
     }
}
```

The view variable is the listview item that is selected. Now, I need to change the view that is selected to another view. **So the question is: can I change the layout of a ListViewItem from the View variable?**

I have NineOldAndroids library imported, maybe that is a solution?

This is the link to my public github where you can find the code for the library: [Github](https://github.com/ghost606/SwipeListView)